# Setting UISplitViewController viewControllers Property Causes SIGABRT in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, sigabrt, portrait

In our app we call a method that adds two navigation controllers to a UISplitViewController via the viewControllers property.  We do this in multiple places in our app, but this one place is causing a SIGABRT and I cannot figure out why.  The UISplitViewController.viewControllers already has two view controllers in the NSArray at this point.  The error happens only when the device is in portrait and only on iOS 8.

The error that comes with the SIGABRT is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'
```

The line of code that causes the error is

```
self.splitViewController.viewControllers =  @[mainNav.navigationController, genericNavVC];
```

It has to be something with the property because it doesn't seem to matter what I try to assign to it (nil, 2 blank UINavigationControllers, etc.).  I've also tried using the setViewControllers method but it still errs.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and is there something we could use as a workaround?

-- Extra Info --

NSLog of the exception callStackSymbols:

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x24ce6d7f <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3285dc77 objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x24bfafb7 <redacted> + 230
    3   myApp                               0x00212ef7 -[DocsToSign objectAtIndex:] + 62
    4   myApp                               0x001436d3 -[DocsToSignListViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 966
    5   UIKit                               0x2845126d <redacted> + 476
    6   UIKit                               0x2845132f <redacted> + 54
    7   UIKit                               0x28446a51 <redacted> + 2276
    8   UIKit                               0x2825ec1b <redacted> + 186
    9   UIKit                               0x28188c1f <redacted> + 514
    10  QuartzCore                          0x27bb3f65 <redacted> + 136
    11  QuartzCore                          0x27baf951 <redacted> + 360
    12  UIKit                               0x2819b367 <redacted> + 138
    13  UIKit                               0x282358ed <redacted> + 872
    14  UIKit                               0x2836643d <redacted> + 284
    15  UIKit                               0x28232803 <redacted> + 78
    16  UIKit                               0x28480949 <redacted> + 536
    17  UIKit                               0x286474cd <redacted> + 168
    18  UIKit                               0x28647283 <redacted> + 138
    19  UIKit                               0x28474487 <redacted> + 350
    20  UIKit                               0x28636d13 <redacted> + 170
    21  myApp                               0x000eb5db -[AppDelegate_iPad ClearDetailView] + 1446
    22  myApp                               0x001478e9 -[DocsToSignListViewController SignDocsComplete:withResponseData:] + 1564
    23  myApp                               0x000fbae3 -[WCFHandler requestCompleted] + 846
    24  myApp                               0x000fc353 -[WCFHandler connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 86
    25  CFNetwork                           0x24840045 <redacted> + 56
    26  CFNetwork                           0x2483ffff <redacted> + 182
    27  CFNetwork                           0x248400f1 <redacted> + 36
    28  CFNetwork                           0x2475527b <redacted> + 78
    29  CFNetwork                           0x247f18c5 <redacted> + 60
    30  CFNetwork                           0x24746189 <redacted> + 60
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x24bf83f1 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
    32  CFNetwork                           0x24746043 <redacted> + 182
    33  CFNetwork                           0x24745f09 <redacted> + 216
    34  CFNetwork                           0x24745da5 <redacted> + 48
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x24cad5e7 <redacted> + 14
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x24cac9fb <redacted> + 222
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x24cab079 <redacted> + 768
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x24bf8981 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x24bf8793 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x2bfa8051 GSEventRunModal + 136
    41  UIKit                               0x281ea981 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    42  myApp                               0x000e8a09 main + 48
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x32df9aaf <redacted> + 2
)
```

And this is from calling thread backtrace at exception time:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2259, 0x000eb71c myApp`-[AppDelegate_iPad ClearDetailView](self=0x15571b80, _cmd=0x002b2ecd) + 1768 at AppDelegate_iPad.m:332, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
  * frame #0: 0x000eb71c myApp`-[AppDelegate_iPad ClearDetailView](self=0x15571b80, _cmd=0x002b2ecd) + 1768 at AppDelegate_iPad.m:332
    frame #1: 0x001478e8 myApp`-[DocsToSignListViewController SignDocsComplete:withResponseData:](self=0x155b7820, _cmd=0x002b968f, handler=0x15511f10, responseData=0x1558ef90) + 1564 at DocsToSignListViewController.m:690
    frame #2: 0x000fbae2 myApp`-[WCFHandler requestCompleted](self=0x1550b040, _cmd=0x2bf7076d) + 846 at WCFHandler.m:161
    frame #3: 0x000fc352 myApp`-[WCFHandler connectionDidFinishLoading:](self=0x1550b040, _cmd=0x2898e975, connection=0x15567af0) + 86 at WCFHandler.m:243
    frame #4: 0x24840044 CFNetwork`__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 56
    frame #5: 0x2483fffe CFNetwork`-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 182
    frame #6: 0x248400f0 CFNetwork`-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 36
    frame #7: 0x2475527a CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 78
    frame #8: 0x247f18c4 CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 60
    frame #9: 0x24746188 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 60
    frame #10: 0x24bf83f0 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
    frame #11: 0x24746042 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
    frame #12: 0x24745f08 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 216
    frame #13: 0x24745da4 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
    frame #14: 0x24cad5e6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    frame #15: 0x24cac9fa CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 222
    frame #16: 0x24cab078 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 768
    frame #17: 0x24bf8980 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #18: 0x24bf8792 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #19: 0x2bfa8050 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #20: 0x281ea980 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #21: 0x000e8a08 myApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x0054cafc) + 48 at main.m:14
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace to your question?  The "index 11" part seems strangely unconnected to the line that's crashing.

Comment: @Alex311 A stack trace would be beneficial

Comment: Traces have been added

Comment: It's not that property. The setter triggers something else. There's an array somewhere else in your app (probably in the same view controller) that has 10 elements.

Comment: We do not subclass the UISplitViewController, so the setter would not be triggering anything with our code.  I was thinking it was doing something behind the scenes that was causing it to err.  I can run the same exact code on a device that still has iOS 7 on it and it runs fine.

Comment: Interesting that the two traces are quite different.  What does `DocsToSign objectAtIndex:` look like?

Comment: I have found the error and the exact spot where the exception is being thrown.  I'm looking into it now and should have a better update on what was causing it soon.